# Can we give Pending as a Role to wp_insert_user?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Can we give role parameter the value of pending in wp_insert_user ?

Comment: This'll assign a custom role `pending`.

Comment: mean do i have to use add_role first ?? and if i have to then can you please tell me that i don't want to give any capability should i just leave the third parameter of add_role empty or anything else?

Comment: yes, make a role called `pending` without third parameter `$capabilities`. and while using `wp_insert_user()` pass role as `pending`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a value as pending *( left the `role` parameter blank )* to not enter a user role value into database using function - `wp_insert_user()`.

See - [`wp-includes/user.php # L1363`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/user.php#L1363)

> #### NOTE -
>
> `wp_insert_user()` function sets a `default` role if you do not provide any role parameter, So if you want to register a user without any capabilities, I think there's only way is register a new role called `pending` without capabilities and use it while calling `wp_insert_user()` functions.